# std::abs with std::transform not working

Tags: c++, stl

Take this example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

void PrintVec(const std::vector<float>&);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

float vals[] = {-1.2,0.0,1.2};
std::vector<float> test(vals, vals + sizeof(vals) / sizeof(float));
std::vector<float> absTest(3);

std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), absTest.begin(), std::abs<float>());

PrintVec(test);
PrintVec(absTest);

return 0;
}

void PrintVec(const std::vector<float> &vec){
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << vec[i] << '\n';
}
return;
}
```

Using both gcc 4.3.4 and VS 2013 I get compiler errors.  For gcc its:

> testTransformAbs.cpp:15: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'

For VS 2013 its:

> error C2062: type 'float' unexpected

If I remove `<float>` then I get this error:

> testTransformAbs.cpp:15: error: no matching function for call to 'abs()'
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:766: note: candidates are: int abs(int)
>   /usr/include/c++/4.3/cstdlib:144: note:                 long int std::abs(long int)
>   /usr/include/c++/4.3/cstdlib:175: note:                 long long int __gnu_cxx::abs(long long int)
>   /usr/include/c++/4.3/cmath:99: note:                 double std::abs(double)
>   /usr/include/c++/4.3/cmath:103: note:                 float std::abs(float)
>   /usr/include/c++/4.3/cmath:107: note:                 long double std::abs(long double)

I can create my own function

```
float MyAbs(float f){
    return sqrt(f * f);
}

std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), absTest.begin(), MyAbs);
```

And everything works.  The reference on cplusplus.com says that the fourth input can be an UnaryOperation defined by:

> Unary function that accepts one element of the type pointed to by InputIterator as argument, and returns some result value convertible to the type pointed to by OutputIterator.
>    This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

To me this should be able to use `std::abs()`.  I also tried `fabs` with the same result.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you pass your own function only by name, but `std::abs<float>()`?

Comment: @Slava I tried it both ways.  Just didn't include all the various ways I tried things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::abs` is an overloaded function, not a template function. When obtaining a pointer to the function, you can choose a specific overload by casting:

```
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), absTest.begin(),
    static_cast<float (*)(float)>(&std::abs));
```

or by using a function pointer variable:

```
float (*fabs)(float) = &std::abs;
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), absTest.begin(), fabs);
```

Note that I also removed the `()` you put after `abs`, since this is a function and not a class that needs to be instantiated.

Comment: Great thanks.  I'm off to read more about function pointers and casting.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::abs` is not a template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). Any function in headers prefixed with a c like `cmath` or `cstdlib` do not have any C++ features like templates, because they represent the C standard library.
Also `std::abs` is for integral types. You should be using [std::fabs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) for floating point types.

I dont like function pointer casts, so in cases like this one, i usually write some wrappers like these:

```
namespace hlp {
template <class T> struct iabs { 
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "");
    T operator()(T const& t){ return std::abs(t); } 
};
template <class T> struct fabs { 
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, ""); 
    T operator()(T const& t){ return std::fabs(t); } 
};
}
```

You can use those wrappers like you wanted to use std::abs in your question.
The `static_assert` will generate a clean compiler error when you try to use the integral version for floating point types or vice versa.