# Another clash between math function with and without std:: prefix

Tags: c++, cmath

I know that this is very old topic, but I can't understand why it behaves like this here.

The program:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a = {1,4,9,16};
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), sqrt); // WORKS
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), std::sqrt); // compilation error
}
```

And the compilation error is

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
  std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), std::sqrt); // compilation error
                                                         ^
........
```

So, in case of

1. `sqrt` the compiler can deduce argument/return types and use this function.
2. `std::sqrt` the compiler can't choose between different overloads of `std::sqrt`?..

Why is this so?
All types are known during compilation, what exactly can't it deduce?
Why just plain `sqrt` works (I can't find definitions)?

---

The following probably shows that something's going on:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    typeid(sqrt); // compiles
    typeid(std::sqrt); // compilation error
}
```

when it says that it can't understand type of `std::sqrt` without context, which makes sense.

So, from this snipped it probably follows that `sqrt` is declared smth like

```cpp
//global namespace
double sqrt(double);
```

while `std::sqrt` has many overloads as shown in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt .

So, my question is three-folded:

1. Are global math functions declared somewhere? I thought when you use it without `std::` it just uses ADL or smth to find it. Also, I'm not including `<math.h>`.
2. How to deal with the situation if `sqrt` is defined in some library, but I want the standard version?
3. Why can't it deduce argument/return type for `std::sqrt`, if it is known?

Comment: Capsule summary: it cannot be deduced because all other parameters to `std::transform` are `std::vector<double>::iterator`. Unfortunately, there is no `std::sqrt` overload that takes that as a parameter.

Comment: recomendation on style: The "ridiculous" is rather prominent in your title. There are reasons why you get the errors you get so it boils down to your misunderstanding, and I wouldn't call that "ridiculous" ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::abs with std::transform not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638832/stdabs-with-stdtransform-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

The key part of the error message is "<unresolved overloaded function type>". There are multiple versions of `std::sqrt` that take different argument types, and there is no way for the compiler to know which one you want in that context.

Apparently, in the global namespace, your compiler provides the C names:

```
float sqrtf(float);
double sqrt(double);
long double sqrtl(long double);
```

There's only one function named `sqrt`, so the compiler knows which one to use.

In the `std` namespace there are more:

```
float sqrt(float);             // 1
float sqrtf(float);
double sqrt(double);           // 2
long double sqrt(long double); // 3
long double sqrtl(long double);
double sqrt(Integral type);    // 4
```

So there are four functions named `std::sqrt`, and the compiler doesn't have any rule for choosing one.

To pick on of the overloads, you use a cast (yes, that's unintuitive, and, frankly, weird):

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), (double (*)(double))std::sqrt)
```

Note that the version marked "WORKS" only works by accident. There is no requirement in C++ that the global namespace has **only** the C names.

Comment: I must add that using MSVC compiler both `sqrt` and `std::sqrt` giving compile errors.

Comment: @MohammadRahimi -- yes, that's what my last two sentences are about.

Answer (score 5):

> Are global math functions declared somewhere? I thought when you use it without `std::` it just uses ADL or smth to find it. Also, I'm not including `<math.h>`.

`<cmath>` may or may not include `<math.h>` and expose the C `sqrt` function because of that.  This is what your implementation is doing.

> How to deal with the situation if `sqrt` is defined in some library, but I want the standard version?

If you want `std::sqrt`, then use `std::sqrt`.  No other function will be used if you do that.

> Why can't it deduce argument/return type for `std::sqrt`, if it is known?

Unlike the C version of `sqrt`, `std::sqrt` is overloaded with

```
float       sqrt ( float arg );
double      sqrt ( double arg );
long double sqrt ( long double arg );
double      sqrt ( IntegralType arg );
```

and the compiler doesn't have a rule for which overload to use when you pass `std::sqrt` to `std::transform`.  To get around that, we can use a lambda to move the call to `sqrt` into a context where the compiler can preform overload reolution.  That would look like

```
std::transform(a.begin(), 
               a.end(), 
               a.begin(), 
               [](auto val){ return std::sqrt(val); });
```

And now the correct version of `std::sqrt` is called for you.